# Arrayformula - Adding together a dynamically generated list of ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to add together a dynamically generated list of ranges using (I'm guessing) an `ARRAYFORMULA`.

The normal way of attacking this is fine if there is a known list of ranges, the example of the results I want would work using this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( A1:A10 + B1:B10 )
```

In the case I'm after I want to add together ranges in multiple sheets.  I don't want the users to have to manually adjust the array formula every time they add a new sheet to be calculated, and I also want to be able to add some logic to include or remove the particular sheet from the calculation, but for now I'm happy to ignore that and just focus on adding cells together.

My approach to this was to create a column with a list of names, each one matching a sheet in the document, and then using that list to dynamically build the list of ranges to add together, using `INDIRECT`.

```
.------------.
| sheet1     |     <---- SheetListNamedRange
|------------|
| sheet2     |
`------------'
```

Here's a quick example

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( INDIRECT("'" & SheetListNamedRange & "'!D4:75") )
```

There are lots of failure modes depending on how it's done, but this particular formula only puts in the values of the first sheet and ignores any others, which I guess makes sense.

What I'm after is kind of the equivalent of `i++` in a loop found in a normal coding language.  Is there some way of making this work?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you'd like to get a list generated based on different ranges across different sheets. If your case is as simple as the one you mention in the beginning of your post, the following would do the job.

```
={Sheet1!A1:A2; Sheet2!B1:B2}
```

If you want the sum of all these values, you can use `SUM`.

```
=SUM({Sheet1!A1:A2; Sheet2!B1:B2})
```

Please let me know if this isn't what you were looking for, so I can change the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can't refer to array of arrays in **`INDIRECT`**. you will need to **`INDIRECT`** each sheet which contains array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT(A1&"!"&"D:D")+
                         INDIRECT(A2&"!"&"D:D")+
                         INDIRECT(A3&"!"&"D:D")+
                         INDIRECT(A4&"!"&"D:D")))
```

[image]

**note1:** in this case result is 25 as sum of 10 + 15.

- **`10`** is sum of **`sheet1!D:D`**
- and **`15`** is sum of **`sheet2!D:D`**

**note2:** there is no sheet3 and sheet4 which is equal to 0 in **`INDIRECT`**

**note3:** **`D:D`** of the sheet where you have the list of sheets needs to be empty

Comment: I was worried that was the case.  It's having to explicitly add the ranges together like that which I'm not keen on.    The programmer in me just wants a foreach loop, where my list represents each sheet to add together in the arrayformula.  The result I'm after is literally the same result when you do `ARRAYFORMULA( A1:A10 + B1:B10)` but without having to hard code the list of ranges